# Error while opening the new activity using the text view

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an app. with `TextView` used the On click attribute on the button but, 
 when I click the text, my app. crashes

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.android.myapp, PID: 10067
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.myapp/com.example.android.myapp.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null objectreference

**My code is**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText e1,e2;
    TextView textView;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Homepage.class));

        }

    }

    public void Register(View view) {
        String email=e1.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=e2.getText().toString().trim();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter the Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter the Pass",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
        }
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

    }

    public void SignIn(View view) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  if(firebaseAuth!=null){
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Homepage.class));

        }
   }
```

why you are getting null in firebaseAuth this link may help you: [why getting null in firebaseAuth object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533159/firebase-getcurrentuser-is-returning-null-in-new-android-activity)

hope this will help you.

Comment: no its doesnt solve my issue when i tried to add your code its hows

Comment: 10-14 17:27:08.174 17039-17039/com.example.android.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.android.myapp, PID: 17039
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.myapp/com.example.android.myapp.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null obje

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue you made my day and save my day