# Android firebaseauth.getCurrentUser() returns null in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the **'getUid'** value from firebase for already existing user in the firebase database. It doesn't work when,

- The app is uninstalled and re-installed again and when logged in
  using already registered user credentials

It works when,

- Registered as a new user and logged in without
  uninstalling the application.

It throws the error saying **getCurrentUser** is null. Below is my code,

```
 private FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
 firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 firebaseauth.getCurrentUser();
 user_id = firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

I want to know why the 'getCurrentUser' returns null for already existing registered user when app is re-installed. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The onAuthListener described here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538113/3655491

Comment: @IvanLeHjelmeland It doesn't work because the first line in that method is firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() and it returns NULL for me

Comment: But what if you add the AuthStateListener instead of just reading out the current user, will you then get a user? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41797358/3655491

Comment: @IvanLeHjelmeland It still retuns null

Comment: If `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns `null`, there is no user currently signed in according to Firebase Authentication. It's impossible to say why that is, without seeing how you sign the user in. I recommend looking at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it more likely we can help.

Comment: Aside from that, I definitely recommend taking Ivan's proposal and using an auth state listener. If that still doesn't fire for your authenticated users, still show the code that you've used in the MCVE, as using an auth state listener rules out a pretty substantial (and tricky) chunk of code in the Firebase Authentication SDK on Android.

Comment: @Mustafa the code OP has added, does that

Comment: @Anusha you should add your code where you have signed in your user.